# Master theorem about polynomial classifiers?

Tags: datasets, generalization

Does anyone know if there is a theorem or counterexample establishing whether or not for any given binary classification task in some finite (possibly large) dimensional vector space of attributes, that there exists a polynomial classifier that can form a hyperplane sorting all the positive from negatively labelled data points?

To clarify, I know that if a dataset is linearly separable, then we can find such a linear classifier. But my question is more general and asks if without knowing beforehand whether a dataset is separable at all, can we know ahead of time if there exists a polynomial classifier for any n-dimensional vector space of data points?

Comment: they are all wrong, check this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549852/can-any-data-be-learned-using-polynomial-logistic-regression (you can obviously ignore the "logistic" part since it's just used to transform it to probability.. the decision boundary is still made by a polynomial function, thus it still holds)

Comment: [Stone-Weierstrass?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something I think you're simply looking for the [Rouche Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem).

A polynomial classifier is just a set of linear equations made of feature vectors and coefficients (parameters) vectors. So to know if a solution exists you would have to compute the rank of the classifier coefficient matrix and expanded matrix and compare their ranks.

Comment: Thanks but unless I misunderstand you, I am interested in the powers and limits of polynomial classifiers to solve binary classification tasks. For example, a set of data labelled such that (0,0) and (1,1) are positive and yet (0,1) and (1,0) are labelled negative, cannot admit of a linear classifier but needs a polynomial one.

Comment: linear or polynomial, a classifier is anyway solved as a set of linear equations, with respect to the coefficient we are solving for. So the theorem should still be applicable.

Comment: to rephrase the idea of the theorem, it's not about dividing the data, that's always possible in theory, cause worst case scenario I can always define n hyper planes, one for each point in my data. It's about how many coefficient (or equations) I can define based on my data that limit the expressive power of a classifier.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a counterexample:

$$
X=(0,1,0,1)\\
Y=(0, 0, 1,1)
$$

No polynomial can separate the values of $Y$.